# check for magic numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I have to give output as line number with "magic number found" msg, for every magic number found

I am parsing a .C file.

magic number is basically

```
if(list == 5)          // here 5 is magic number

for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)        //here 6 is magic number
```

MY CODE

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $input) or die $!;                                          
my @lines = <FILE>;
my $count = 0; 

foreach(@lines){
     $count++;
 if($_ =~ 'for\('){                       # I want to check within for( )
        if($_ =~ '#####'){                  # how do the check for numbers
           print "magic number found at line:".$count;
   }
  }
     elif($_ =~ 'if\('){                       # I want to check within if( )
        if($_ =~ '#####'){                  
           print "magic number found at line:".$count;
  }
 }
}
```

As magic number exists only in for loop and if loop, so i want to check within bracket if there exist any **decimal or hexadecimal value**.

Comment: I think it's far more complex than that `regex` check. How about a `for` where each clause is in different lines? Or a variable named `i345` instead of `i`? To say only a few issues.

Comment: @Birei yes true...dnt think about that.then any other way of doing it

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to parse C code, but you never once mention it in your question? Perhaps you should?

Comment: Perl::Critic has a policy on this, perhaps it will help: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ValuesAndExpressions/ProhibitMagicNumbers.pm

Comment: @RobEarl thanks for the link. will try the Perl::Critic module

Comment: If you are parsing C source code with regexes, stop right *now*. You are entering a world of bugs and pain. Use a proper parser, and operate on the AST. This ought to pay off in the long run. I can't recommend any library, but I know of [MarpaX::Languages::C::AST](https://metacpan.org/pod/MarpaX::Languages::C::AST) – however, that runs the preprocessor before parsing the code.

Comment: @amon thanks for tips. i will look into AST. parsing C code with regex has been lot of pain for me and i was searching for some alternate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Edited again. This time as for `if` condition, it first matches paired parentheses, and then looks for a number after `==`.

I've made it more robust, for that it will recognise multiline condition testing. However, as other said, this might still not cover 100% of the possible cases.

```
use 5.14.0;
use warnings;

my $data = join '', <DATA>;

my $if = qr/if \s* ( \( (?: [^()]++ | (?-1) )*+ \) ) /spx; # matching paired parenthesis
my $for = qr/for (\s*\(.*?;.*?) (\d+) \s*? ; /spx; #(\d+) is for the Magic Number

for($data){
    while (/$if/g){
        my $pat = ${^MATCH};
        my $line =()= ${^PREMATCH} =~ /\n/g;
        # assumes a magic number exists only when '==' is present
        if ($pat =~ /(.* == \s* )([0-9a-fA-F.]+)\s*\)/x){
            my $mn = $2;
            my $condition = $1;
            $line += () = $condition =~ /\n/g;
            say "Line ", $line + 1," has magic number $mn";
        }
    }
    while (/$for/g){
        my $mn = $2; #Magic Number
        my $condition = $1; #For counting \n in the MATCH.
        my $line =()= ${^PREMATCH} =~ /\n/g; #Counting \n in the PREMATCH.
        $line += () = $condition =~ /\n/g;
        say "Line ", $line + 1," has magic number $mn";
    }
}


__DATA__
if(list ==
5)          // here 5 is magic number

for(int i = 0; i<6
 ;
i++
)        //here 6 is magic number

if(list ==
8)          // here 8 is magic number

if (IsMirrorSubChainEnable())
{
    err = ChainCtrlSetMirrorSC(pChainCtrl, pNewRouteInfo);
}

ModCallCallbacks((ModT *)pChainCtrl, kDoneVinResetCallback, NULL, 0);
```

Output:

```
Line 2 has magic number 5
Line 10 has magic number 8
Line 4 has magic number 6
```

Comment: it works fine. But as pointed out by user birei, If the conditional statement is multiline then It wnt give desire output

Comment: @Ad-vic: I would say this is still useful as a non-strict aid to finding some code issues. If that is what this is for, then think of return-on-investment. This code is simple and will find maybe 75% of what you want. In addition you are then likely to fire up an editor and start fixing, and will find some more. Getting more accuracy in your "magic number finder" takes time away from your fixing . . .

Comment: @jing thanks. it is perfect just as i wanted. you helped me a lot. Is it anyway possible to include hexadecimal as hexadecimal can also be magic number

Comment: @Ad-vic: You may change the `$if` regex to `my $if = qr/if (\s*\(.*?) ([0-9a-fA-F.]+) \s* \) /spx;`, in that `[0-9a-fA-F.]+` will recognise both decimal and hex numbers. I put a `.` in there just in case if you have something like `if (list == 8.8)`. If not required, you may simply remove the dot from the regex, making the class `[0-9a-fA-F]+`. `for` loops usually don't have such issues and I guess you can leave `$for` regex in peace.

Comment: @jing the code is giving lots of wrong results in running a demo c file

Comment: if I run user jing code in a sample c file containing following lines

...
if (IsMirrorSubChainEnable())
    {
        err = ChainCtrlSetMirrorSC(pChainCtrl, pNewRouteInfo);
    }

    ModCallCallbacks((ModT *)pChainCtrl, kDoneVinResetCallback, NULL, 0);

    ...

it gives output as

Line 6 has magic number 0

But line 6 has no magic number.I only need to check within if and for loop statement

Comment: @Ad-vic: Thanks for pointing out the error. I've updated the answer. This time for the `if` condition, the code tries to find paired parentheses before looking for the magic number. I guess this is a much safer attempt. Let me know if there's further problems.

Comment: @jing thanks for helping me with all cases. I will definitely try for all cases as I have to make it bugfree and let you know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39930/discussion-between-ad-vic-and-jing-yu)

Comment: @jing. there is one more bug with hexadecimal.if i run with this part of the code.. if (pDstChain->chainCompInfo.bCanComposit == false)
{}...the output comes out as Line 1 has magic number f

Comment: @Ad-vic: sorry, didn't see you in the chat-room. I've updated the code again. I'll be away for some good hours. But will be back to see how this goes. Cheers.

Comment: @jing Its not working for cases if(list ==
5.5) even if you used [0-9a-fA-F.]